# Web server with a private IP

Tags: networking, firewall, router, nat, local-area-network

I need an explanation of how to establish tcp/ip connection to two web servers that are on a remote lan network. The web servers have a private IP addresses.

Let say of the sites is https://justanexplanation.org

Will DNS return to me a public address of the router/lan where servers sits? As far as know this is the only address that dns can know.

But, how the de-encapsulation will continue than if I only know public ip, how the 'destination' lan knows which server is right for this connection since both operate on port 80.

I am confused.

Thanks

Comment: Are the "servers" on separate physical machines or the sameone? If same one then served pages will come from domain name specified in browser. Otherwise if accessing via IP Address they will be handled as one. Do you have static IP or dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get around this with port forwarding.  Forward port 80 > 80 on one of the servers and 81 > 80 on the other.

Then from outside you can do [www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com) to get to the first server and [www.domain2.com:81](http://www.domain2.com:81) to get to the other.

Another alternative would be to run both sites on the same server and let the web server itself sort out which pages to serve.

Comment: That's not what I would recommend, since this is a bad practice for users. Use a reverse proxy instead.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a load balancer. This service distributes connections to backend servers. Typically implemented with a reverse proxy. Connection routing rules are whatever you wish, often based on HTTP Host headers or backend health.

> Will DNS return to me a public address of the router/lan where servers sits? As far as know this is the only address that dns can know.

DNS is merely a database, which can hold any IP address you like, and other data. Of course, RFC 1918 private addresses are not routable via the internet, where you need public IP space.

If lacking globally routable IP addresses is a problem for you, implement IPv6. v6 has more than enough address space for every device to have globally routable IP addresses. Likely you will still want a load balancer type service for various reasons, but end to end connectivity is easier to understand.

Answer (score -1):

> Will DNS return to me a public address of the router/lan where servers sits?

The DNS will return WHAT IT IS TOLD TO RETURN. Main problem is - do you have a STATIC IP? Or not? Anyhow, yes, it should end there.

> As far as know this is the only address that dns can know.

No, DNS can know any address that is put into it. This is the only one that makes sense - but basically, you ask "where can I go with a car". Whever you want. You can point a domain to whatever IP you want.

> But, how the de-encapsulation will continue than if I only know public ip, how the
> 'destination' lan knows which server is right for this connection since both operate on
> port 80.

Like a taxi - somoene tells the driver. The taxi in this case being the router that handles your network. Configure it to port forward. How? The manual helps.